# Is there a default Android view widget with textbox and 2 knobs?

Tags: android-layout, android-widget, android, android-view

Is there a default view that allows a number textbox, which can be changed by typing in the textbox or by two adjacent knobs by the textbox. So basically, in awesome ASCII graphics:

[<] [textbox] [>]

Basically an increment button, textbox, and decrement button.

Comment: no there is not one built into SDK.

Comment: No, there is not in SDK. But you can create your own from a textview and 2 buttons and make it reusable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since API level 11, you can now use the NumberPicker;

You can find the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html)

You can find an example [here](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/android/6418-android-adventures-pickers.html?start=2)

Comment: The default NumberPicker is vertical only, not horizontal as described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

My custom solution using EditText and two Button objects:

```
    // This is a textbox group with two knob buttons
    LinearLayout boxGroup = new LinearLayout(this);
    boxGroup.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    //Stores the current value in the textbox
    final int[] value = {0};

    // Editable text box
    final EditText editText = new EditText(this);
    editText.setText("" + value[0]);

    // Decrement button
    Button decrementButton = new Button(this);
    decrementButton.setText("<");
    decrementButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            value[0]++;
            editText.setText("" + value[0]);
        }
    });

    // Increment button
    Button incrementButton = new Button(this);
    incrementButton.setText(">");
    incrementButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            value[0]--;
            editText.setText("" + value[0]);
        }
    });

    boxGroup.addView(decrementButton);
    boxGroup.addView(editText);
    boxGroup.addView(incrementButton);
```